# Reversing a list with pop & insert

Tags: python, list

Any ideas why `reverse_1` reverses input list but `reverse_2` doesn't?

I have run both in the debugger and the issue seems to be that `reverse_2` doesn't return the reversed list.

```
def reverse_1(seq):
    return_list = list()
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        return_list.append(seq.pop())
    seq.extend(return_list)


def reverse_2(seq):
    length = len(seq)
    for i in range(length):
        seq.insert(0, seq.pop())


example = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
reverse_1(example) #OUTPUT - [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
reverse_2(example) #OUTPUT - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

`.insert(0, n)` will insert `n` in front of the list, so in the first iteration it pops `6` and inserts it at the beginning:

```
[6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The second iteration will pop `5` and similarly insert it:

```
[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

A possible solution would be to change the line to:

```
seq.insert(i, seq.pop())
```